# How do i add an action listener to a JList in a proper way?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jlist

I'm trying to add an actionListener to a JList, so whenever a user click a value in the JList , it will just println the value.

Here's the code

```
public class FontProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Fonts Frame");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        GraphicsEnvironment e = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        String[] fontNames = e.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();




        JComboBox fontbox = new JComboBox(fontNames);

        JList fontList = new JList(fontNames);
        JButton button = new JButton("Submit");

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();

        scrollPane.setViewportView(fontList);

        fontList.addListSelectionListener(new SharedListSelectionHandler());
        panel.add(fontbox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        mainFrame.add(panel);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.setSize(250, 250);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    }

}
```

Here's the result of the codes

[image]

So how do I add an action Listener to the JList?

Comment: Adding MouseListener?, can I use addActionListener instead?

Comment: No.  Presumably you tried using `list.addActionListener(...)` and found that the method does not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to add an actionListener to a JList,

You can't, it doesn't have `ActionListener` support

> so whenever a user click a value in the JList , it will just println the value.

Use a `ListSelectionListener` instead

Take a look at [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and [How to Write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) for more details