# How to add a "listener" to a JList

Tags: java, swing, sockets, jlist

I know that `JList` doesn't support `ActionListeners` as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31239833/4253314), but I need to implement a list that keeps changing in the frame when new sockets connect to the server. So my question: What is the best way to implement this list?

Comment: so your list should get updated when a new socket  is connected. what does it have to do with a actionListner

Comment: well i imagine that to update a list when some thing happen, it need to have a listener waiting this thing, right?

Answer (score 2):

```
DefaultListModel<String> data = new DefaultListModel<>();  //defaultlistModel

/**
adding data to jlist    **/
       data.addElement("new element");
       jList1.setModel(data);



/**action listner on data(defaultlistModel) will be called when the list is changed*/

    public void addlistner(){


    data.addListDataListener(new ListDataListener() {
        @Override
        public void intervalAdded(ListDataEvent e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void intervalRemoved(ListDataEvent e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void contentsChanged(ListDataEvent e) {
            System.out.println("added"+e.getIndex1());   
        }
    });

    }
```

you cant do that with a `jlist` . but its possible with `defaultListModel` 
whenever you need to add data to the jlist . you should add your element to the `defaultlistmodel` and then set the model in to the `jlist`.
and you can then write a listner to get called on changing properties in `defaultListModel` . take a look at my code.

Comment: Additional info: when using a `JList.setModel()` beware of using `JList.setListData()` - this constructs a new Model and the old model with its listensers will be gone!